# CSS float element

Tags: html, css

How I can do the row's (the red background div) get 100% width when is space for this (under the right element)?

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/TXDWj/

Html code:

```
 <div class="left"></div> <div class="right"></div>

 <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>

 <div class="row">Lorem ipsum dolor ....</div>

 <div class="row">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>

 <div class="row">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>

 <div class="row">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</div>
```

And this css code:

```
.right {width:170px; height:250px; float:right; background:lime;}
.left {width:60px; height:100px; float:left; background:blue;}
.text {float:left; background:aqua; padding:10px; width:400px}
.row {float:left; background:red; margin:5px 0 0 60px; padding:10px; width:60%;}
```

**Update:**

exptect behaviors can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/TXDWj/22/

but without having the "row_extra" class ... or beter view to get an idea: http://jsfiddle.net/TXDWj/37/

thanks all of you

Comment: I think that I don't understand what you want to do :S why don't set `.row{... width: 100%;}`?

Comment: because with row set to 100% ... all will go under the green right div, I just want to have the row under the text (aqua div) of all hight of the green div..and after to have full width.

Comment: also ..for the 'real usage' of this..I can not remove the float from row divs..so if you know some possibilities to obtain that effect (http://jsfiddle.net/TXDWj/37/)

Comment: Is the background color important, or is that only for demonstration purposes?

Comment: And can you explain why `.row` must have a float?

Comment: derek: the bg is just for demo;

Comment: @menocchio, if I can remove float from `.row` I'll post a working answer from you.  Otherwise, I can't.

Comment: and the row..don;t need to have float but I need them like block (in the website each is a box with some rounded corner so it need to have "box model on them")... that's why the solution with row 100% it is not good for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the float from `.row` and clear floats to the left.

```
.row {
    background: red;
    margin: 5px 0 0 60px;
    padding: 10px;
    clear: left;
}
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TXDWj/44/)

(Ignore that the red background goes under the green background, as the colors are just for demo.  I've also given extra margin to some of the other DIVs to closer approximate your layout, but again that's just for demo.)

Comment: The red div (.row div) are not just for demo..the other div color is just for demo propose
is my fault..I was no so clear on your question ...
And in the end..I guess ..it is not posible to obtain this effect...

Comment: You could do it with JavaScript / jQuery.

Comment: by counting the row div and force different css rules after first two? I guess.. no? I will give a try

Comment: No, by calculating available width and applying it.  You would then be floating `.row`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change  Width:100%;